# Can I request to see a deleted answer on my question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, community-wiki

Quite a while ago I asked a question "[If any object of the java abstract class “Number” is equal to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25252441/1248889)"

There was multiple answers, mostly advising to do `number.doubleValue() == 0`, However each time someone gave this answer, they were immediately downvoted. They would then delete their answer (I assume to avoid further downvotes), then the next person would come in and give this same answer. One person waited long enough for people to have a conversation in the comments and say *why* it was a bad answer. By the time they resolved why, they had around a -5, then deleted their answer.

I wanted to post a community wiki answer one why you shouldn't use that method, but I could no longer see the answer/comments of that deleted answer. I found out that the privilege to [view deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) posts required 10,000 reputation. Can I request to see a deleted answer and the associated comments, or is the right answer to wait until I have enough reputation?

Comment: The best general solution is to visit [chat].  You will usually find a 10K user who will help you retrieve a specific answer from a question.

Comment: You *can*, but why would you want to tell people how *not* to do it? Why not just leave it at how it should be done?

Comment: @TinyGiant because sometimes novices need to know why not to do something stupid.

Comment: Or you could just tell them the right way, avoiding the possibility that they don't read the "don't do it this way" part of the answer and use the bad code. @psubsee2003

Comment: @TinyGiant Considering that several people tried to give similar bad advice it seems to hold that a "Don't do X because of Y" may be in order.

Comment: ... or downvotes and delete votes of subsequent bad answers are in order. @apaul34208

Comment: Here you go: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YE0Qc.png

Comment: @TinyGiant Ya... crap should be deleted, particularly redundant crap, but  saving people a few hours/headaches by explaining why their clever idea isn't so clever seems like the right thing to do. Making the internet a better place n' all, right?

Comment: I really can't get behind the idea that telling users how not to accomplish a task is making the internet a better place. If a user tries something the wrong way, and it doesn't work, they'll post a question about it, where someone will educate them about why they can't / shouldn't do it that way. @apaul34208

Comment: @TinyGiant I guess my question was focus too much on my experience. I was trying to provide an example of a valid motive to request to seeing something I do not yet have the Privilege of seeing. I think psubsee2003's comment on the chat is fantastic, and I didn't know the chat even existed. Whether or not making a community wiki about what *not* to do and why, may be another (meta)question entirely I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25252542/1529630), which had 3 downvotes and 1 upvote.

The main comments were

> Won't work if the `Number` is capable of holding a value with finer
>   precision than a `double` (for example, an arbitrary-precision number
>   library). – [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) Aug 11 '14 at 21:18

> What if it's `BigDecimal`? – [PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1) Aug 11 '14 at 21:20

> And in the case of `BigDecimal`? Or `MyNumber`? This is also wrong,
>   but will cause much more insidious bugs than the (now deleted)
>   `intValue()` suggestion. – [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) Aug 11 '14 at 21:21

> additionally, comparing Double or Float for equality never works as
>   expected - in fact, i doubt it even works AT ALL (someone correct me
>   if im wrong) - without a sensible delta, equals or == makes no sense
>   with floating-point types. – [specializt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351861/specializt) Aug 11 '14 at 21:22

> It should be obvious that "best bet" is not good enough. If the
>   question was "how can I check whether a `Number` is zero some of the
>   time" then this would certainly be an answer. But so would `.equals(0)`.
>   – [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) Aug 11 '14 at 21:22

> "i hid the problem since it doesnt affect my right now, therefore it
>   doesnt exist". I think your "best bet" isnt enough. At least throw
>   RuntimeException if your method doesnt receive pre-set instances of
>   Number, that will at least avoid the BIGGEST mistakes. –
>   [specializt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351861/specializt) Aug 11 '14 at 21:24

> Almost all dealings requiring accurate representations of decimal
>   quantities use `BigDecimal` - money for example *should* be
>   represented as a `BigDecimal`. – [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) Aug 11 '14 at
>   21:26

I didn't include comments from the author because, since he deleted the answer, he might not want it to be associated with him.

Comment: Huh, only 3 downvotes and 1 upvote? My poor memory of -5 must have been exaggerated. Thank you!